# htaccess how to delete multiple extensions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I wanna delete 2 extensions from my URL (png, gif)
My code looks like that but only the first type of extension works e.g. when png is first the extension is deleted but you cant open gif image, when i change png to gif i can open gif without extension but i cant open png image.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.png [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.gif [NC,L]






RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+\.png)$ /imgs/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^./]+\.gif)$ /imgs/$1 [L,NC]
```

My .htaccess is in the main directory,

It's just main directory > imgs

In the "imgs" folder you can find only .png and .gif files.

Comment: And you're accessing, for eg. `localhost/imgs/23252768.gif` or `localhost/imgs/23252768` or `localhost/23252768.gif`?

Comment: i'm trying to make it available from localhost/23252768
But when i'm using that way I only can do this for gif image.
For png i need to add .png on the end

Comment: I've updated my reply below. Please try with the new snippet.

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much.

Comment: Good to know! :) Also, please mark the answer as selected, so that it won't appear as an unanswered question anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're internally writing the URLs back to have `.png` or `.gif` extensions, you'll need to check their existence as well, otherwise, a path like `/path/to/image.gif` will be redirected to `/path/to/image`, and will **always** be rewritten to `/path/to/image.png`, which doesn't exist.

Give the following rule set a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/imgs%{REQUEST_URI}.png -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.png [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/imgs%{REQUEST_URI}.gif -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.gif [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)\.(gif|png)$ /imgs/$1.$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: with that code gif image is working but png not
server respond for png image "The requested URL /imgs/23252768.gif was not found on this server."

It looks like it's searching for gif instead of png.

Comment: @adamadamowki Can you please provide as to where your htaccess file is, what is the server directory structure and which file are you accessing? Please edit the same in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(.*?)\.(png|gif)[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule  (.*)$  /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```